# Mapping DTO an Entity, leave entity null if all your field is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct, modelmapper

My entity is return fields null example: EntityTest{id=null, name=null}

but I need that if all fields are null return EntityTest = null

**TestEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TestEntity")
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="test_name")
    private String testName;
}
```

**TestEntityDto**

```
public class TestEntityDto {

    private long id;
    private String test_name;
}
```

**TestEntityMapper**

```
@Mapper
public interface TestEntityMapper {
    TestEntity TestEntityDTOToTestEntity(TestEntityDTO testEntityDTO);
```

Implementa

```
testEntityDTO.setId(null);
testEntityDTO.setNameTest(null);
TestEntity testEntity = TestEntityMapper.TestEntityDTOToTestEntity(testEntityDTO);
```

**Actual Result:**

```
EntityTest{id=null, name=null}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
EntityTest = null
```

Comment: That's not how it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest implementing toString only to check the all null case:

```
toString(){"id:"+id+",name:"+name;}
```

So if this returns "id:null,name:null" then you can be sure it's null and return null after checking equals

Comment: but you say after doing the mapping, DTO to Entity?

Comment: Yes this can be done after the mapping

Comment: thank you, that  work for me

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming 1.5 release MapStruct is adding support for conditional mapping. In the current released Beta2 of 1.5 there is no support for conditional support parameters. However, there is an open [enhancement request](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2610) to add this for source parameters.

What this means is that you can do something like:

```
public class MappingUtils {

    @Condition
    public static boolean isPresent(TestEntityDTO dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return dto.getId() != null || dto.getName() != null;
    }

}
```

Which means that you can have a mapper like:

```
@Mapper(uses = MappingUtils.class)
public interface TestEntityMapper {

    TestEntity testEntityDTOToTestEntity(TestEntityDTO testEntityDTO);

}
```

and the implementation will look like:

```
public class TestEntityMapperImpl implements {

    @Override
    public TestEntity testEntityDTOToTestEntity(TestEntityDTO dto) {
        if (!MappingUtils.isPresent(dto)) {
            return null
        }

        // the rest of the mapping
    }
}
```

Note: this is not yet possible in a release version, but this is how it will work. Apart from this future solution there is no other solution out-of-the-box with MapStruct.